# Couldn't read row 1, col -1 from CursorWindow

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have the following error message in my application:

```
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.unserekinder/com.example.unserekinder.Ereignisse}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 1, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 1, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at com.example.unserekinder.Ereignisse.datenfuerlistviewereignis(Ereignisse.java:49)
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at com.example.unserekinder.Ereignisse.onCreate(Ereignisse.java:28)
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-13 09:05:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     ... 11 more
```

My table looks like this:

```
public static final String ereignisid = "id";
public static final String TABLE_NAME_EREIGNIS="ereignis";
public static final String EREIGNISNAME = "ereignisname";
public static final String EREIGNISZEIT = "ereigniszeit";
public static final String EREIGNISGENAUERES = "ereignisgenaueres";
public static final String KINDID = "kindid";

private static final String TABLE_EREIGNIS_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_EREIGNIS + " (" + ereignisid + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + EREIGNISNAME + " TEXT, " + EREIGNISZEIT + " TEXT, " + EREIGNISGENAUERES + " TEXT, " + KINDID + " INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (" + KINDID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_NAME_Kind + "(" + id + "));";
```

This is the function where the error happens:

```
private ArrayList<Ereignis> datenfuerlistviewereignis(){
        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);
        ArrayList<Ereignis> arr = new ArrayList<Ereignis>();
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvEreignisse);
        id = getIntent().getIntExtra("kinderid", 0);
        System.out.println("SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSss" + id);
        Cursor c = db.selectEreignis(id);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int count = c.getCount();
        int i = 0;

        while(c.moveToNext())
        { 


 // here happens the error!
                arr.add(new Ereignis(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ereigniszeit")), c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ereignisname")) ));



            i++;
        }
        if(arr.size() > 0){
            return arr;
        }
        else{
            ArrayList<Ereignis> arrempty = new ArrayList<Ereignis>();
            arrempty.add(new Ereignis("Keine Daten vorhanden", " "));
            return arrempty;
        }
    }
```

Can someone tell me where my mistake is??

**EDIT:**

This is `selectEreignis()`

```
public Cursor selectEreignis(int kindid){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT ereignisname FROM EREIGNIS WHERE KINDID = " + kindid, null);

    System.out.println("HALLLIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII"  + cursor.getCount());
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Couldn´t read row 0 - cursor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467571/couldnt-read-row-0-cursor)

Comment: The answer in the other question isn´t the right one.

Comment: check your column name are same when you use this c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ereigniszeit")) andc.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ereignisname"))

Comment: I´m sure that the column names are the same!

Comment: Post your selectEreignis method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT ereignisname FROM EREIGNIS WHERE KINDID = " + kindid, null);
```

change it to

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT ereignisname, ereigniszeit  FROM EREIGNIS WHERE KINDID = " + kindid, null);
```

Do something like this if your table and query are fine.

```
    if(c.moveToFirst())
    {
    do
    {
    // your array stuff here
    }while(c.moveToNext());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

"ereigniszeit" isn't in the schema as a column name.  Possibly a typo.  Or possibly your selectEreignis function isn't asking for that column.

Comment: What do you mean with "isn´t in the schema"?

Comment: "Schema" is the name for the data description in a database-  all the tables, columns, views, etc.  I'm saying either that isn't the name of a column (possibly due to a typo), or your select function there isn't asking for that column in the set of columns to query.  Due to me not speaking German (?) I'm having a hard time seeing which one it is.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to change the column name ereigniszeit or ereignisname and then try.Because this variable may be declared already in sqlite database schema

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I added `ereigniszeit` in my `selectEreignis()` function.

Comment: Now it work right? but you have to remove c.moveToFirst otherwise you will miss a row